# Python swap elements

Tags: python, arrays, swap

I know there are at least these two methods:

```
array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
```

And:

```
temp = array[i]
array[i] = array[j]
array[j] = temp
```

And in my testing of code that calls my swap function hundreds of thousands of times, the second approach is actually faster.

The problem is, I'd like to know if there's an even faster way of doing it.

I thought about allocating temp in the outer scope so that it doesn't have to be allocated every time swap is called, but that didn't help.

Edit: I'm using this to implement a min heap with tens of thousands of elements in the heap.

Also, I cannot use numpy. If arrays in python are like linked-lists, would simulating a true array using a dictionary with index numbers as keys be a better idea?

Comment: The difference is minimal, if even significant: in my test, the tuple-unpacking version is 193 ns vs 202 ns for the temp variable.

Comment: Python is not the language you want if you are especially concerned with finding the fastest possible way to do tiny tasks like this.

Comment: Nothing gets allocated; that's not how Python variables work. `temp` is just another name that refers to whatever object `array[i]` refers to.

Comment: If you want a real improvement, it'll have to be in that *"code that calls my swap function hundreds of thousands of times"* that you're not showing us.

Answer (score 2):

At lower level, the only difference between the two ways of swapping elements is in the fact that

```
array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
```

performs a [`ROT_TWO`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dis.html) in order to swaps the two top-most stack items, while

```
temp = array[i]
array[i] = array[j]
array[j] = temp
```

uses a temporary variable to store the intermediate result.
This does not lead to any significant difference and the two methods should be almost equivalent in terms of performances, even though some small difference might depend from the OS. As an example, for my systems, the first method is 1.5% faster.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw you added "implement a min heap" to the question. You might be able to make it a little bit faster by keeping the "currently sifting" value in an extra variable instead of inside the list.

Swapping two list elements:

```
> python -m timeit -s "a = [1, 2]; i = 0; j = 1" "a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]"
2000000 loops, best of 5: 169 nsec per loop
```

Swapping a list element with an outside variable:

```
> python -m timeit -s "x = 1; a = [1, 2]; j = 1" "x, a[j] = a[j], x"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 101 nsec per loop
```

And if the "currently sifting" value remains the same, you might not even have to swap at all:

```
> python -m timeit -s "a = [1, 2]; i = 0; j = 1" "a[i] = a[j]"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 91.3 nsec per loop
```

Depends on your code, though, which we still can't see.

Answer (score -1):

So the following assumes that array is a python `List`, which in memory acts like a linked list (not an array as it is typically used in e.g. 'C')

Also, you cannot pre-allocate space for a variable (as you tried to do with `temp`) as every variable in Python is only a reference to a memory address, so every time you do `temp = array[i]` temp will be assigned to the reference of `array[i]` (which is already in memory as it is already in `array`.

What you could try is to invert the list using either `list(reversed([array]))` or `array[::-1]`, whichever you find more readable.

If you in fact have an array (assuming `numpy` here; this is more like a 'C' array), you could do

```
swapped_array = array[:, [1, 0]]  # Reads as 'Select all rows (:) of column 1 and then column 0
```

which should be instant as numpy will not move elements in memory, but just 'assign' column 1 to column 0 and vice versa.

Comment: Why would you assume a linked list? That would be very unusual and insane.

Comment: @HeapOverflow because there is no native array in python and the poster does say it in the above `Also, I cannot use numpy. If arrays in python are like linked-lists, would simulating a true array using a dictionary with index numbers as keys be a better idea?`

Comment: The OP edited that in after your answer. Most certainly you already managed to mislead them into thinking that Python's `list` is a linked list.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Well even though most common low level implementations of `list` are not a naive linked list but rather a dynamic array of pointers, I am not a hundred percent certain if this is constrained this way by the specification. Anyway, I believe that the OP might have more fundamental problems and might be better off providing a longer code sample for us to help him.

Comment: A linked list would result in a lot of code having much worse asymptotic complexity; I'm not sure if the "spec" includes performance requirements or not, but no implementation designed for actually running programs would consider doing this. (Implementations designed for use in analyzing programs may well find linked lists to work quite well, assuming they found anything static enough to be worth analyzing.)